# How can I create and JS variable inside a HTML code from Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this HTML code:

```
// Also, I have this GS code:
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('teste2');
}

function pegador(){
  var data = {
    'nodes': [
    {'id': 'A'},
    {'id': 'B'},
    {'id': 'C'},
    {'id': 'D'},
    {'id': 'E'}
  ],
    'edges': [
    {'from': 'A', 'to': 'B'},
    {'from': 'A', 'to': 'C'},
    {'from': 'A', 'to': 'D'},
    {'from': 'D', 'to': 'C'},
    {'from': 'E', 'to': 'D'}
  ]};

  return data;
}

// Finally, this one:
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutputFromFile('teste2')
      .setHeight(920)
      .setWidth(1900);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModelessDialog(html, 'MCE');
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script
      src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.8.0/js/anychart-core.min.js">
    </script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.8.0/js/anychart-graph.min.js">
    </script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.8.0/js/anychart-data-adapter.min.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
      var data1;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ret){
        data1 = ret;
        return;
      }).pegador();

      var chart1;

      anychart.onDocumentLoad(function() {
        var stage = acgraph.create('container');
        // Chart 1
        chart1 = anychart.graph();
        chart1.data(data1);
        chart1.background().fill({
          src:
            '[image_url]',
          mode: 'fit'
        });
        chart1.title().enabled(true).text('Chart 1. Raw data');
        //chart1.bounds(0, 0, '50%', '50%');
        chart1.container(stage).draw();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me understand why `"chart1.data(data1);"` does not recognize the object as a list? I'm having trouble finding out this solution.. it appears that the `"data"` object is not there.

I'm not sure if the problem is getting the data from a range or getting it as a JS variable inside an HTML file.

Comment: This is most likely happening because `data1` will still be `undefined` by the time that part of your code runs

Comment: Make sure that `ret` meets these requirements for [parameters and return values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

Comment: @fortunee that is exactly what is happening! Any tips in how to fix this?

Comment: I also changed "data1" inside the success handler function to a simple string. Yet, I'm getting undefined.

Comment: @HigorAugustoGomes I just posted an answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: @Cooper I did! Ret is either a string or an array (I have tried both types).

Comment: Consider adding the `google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)` to see what could be causing it to fail @HigorAugustoGomes

Answer (score 0):

### When passing objects in Apps Script from serverside to clientside, you should stringify them

Try the following:

*code.gs*

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('teste2');
}

function pegador(){
  var data = {
    'nodes': [
    {'id': 'A'},
    {'id': 'B'},
    {'id': 'C'},
    {'id': 'D'},
    {'id': 'E'}
  ],
    'edges': [
    {'from': 'A', 'to': 'B'},
    {'from': 'A', 'to': 'C'},
    {'from': 'A', 'to': 'D'},
    {'from': 'D', 'to': 'C'},
    {'from': 'E', 'to': 'D'}
  ]};

  return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

*index.html*

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
      var data1;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).pegador();
      function onSuccess(ret) {
        data1 = JSON.parse(ret);
        // to verify if the success handler has been called:
        console.log("Success");
      }
      function onFailure(error) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
      }

    ...
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, @ziganotschka! Thank you for your answer. I am still getting "undefined" for my data1 variable. It seems that `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).pegador()` it's not running at all.

Comment: This is strange. See if putting the code within the head instead of the body changes anything. Did you republish the WebApp as a new version after incorporating the changes?  Did you have a look at the execution logs?